# Deploying complete SG fails when there commitment error with one of the pages

Tags: content-delivery, deployer, sites-9

We noticed that when publishing a **successfully** rendered SG. The deployment of it fails completely when there's a commitment error with one of the pages. Shouldn't the pages which are correctly rendered inside the SG be deployed instead of rolling back the complete SG?

Version: SDL Tridion Sites 9

Answer (score 3):

This is by design, as there are occasions when you don't want a partial publish (i.e. some pages published but others not). For example, if this is a new section on a site and the section landing page doesn't publish, then you may not want the other pages published (and potentially appearing in the sitemap)

If you want to publish the pages individually then you can just select them. Alternatively, if there are lots of nested structure groups then you can use Advanced Search to just show the pages.

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure about this behaviour? This would mean that if you publish on Root level everything will be rolled back if there's somewhere a commitment error. This is not what you want when you want to republish your complete website.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that's how it works. Maybe someone from the SDL Product team could confirm, but I'm 99% certain.